# How to fix cant perform react state update on an unmounted even use effect has cleanup

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a problem on my project, I'm new to react native the problem is that I'm getting this warning `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

so I tried the cleanup function so all my useEffect looks like this

```
useEffect(()=>{
    let mounted = true
    if (mounted) {
        store.subscribe(()=>{
            SetPlaylistData(store.getState().reducer.playlist)
        })
    }
    return () => {
        mounted = false;
    };
})
```

I'm also using useFocusEffect which looks

```
useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
        let mounted = true
        console.log("user info", store.getState().reducer.userInfo);
        if (mounted) {
            fetchPlaylist(store.getState().reducer.userInfo)
        }
        return () => {
            mounted = false;
          };
    }, [])
  );
```

so my concern is just is there any way that this warning is produce not by useEffect?

Comment: Setting a local variable inside your `useEffect` (like you're trying to do with `let mounted = true`) won't have any effect. Instead, is it possible to call an unsubscribe e method of some sort on your `store`?

Comment: like this? ` store.subscribe(()=>{
           if(isMounted){
            SetPlaylistData(store.getState().reducer.playlist)}
        })`

Comment: No -- I'm asking if there's an `unsubscribe` method you can call on `store`

Comment: oh i look it up on the documentation so its says to just like this `const unsubscirbe = store.subscribe(()=>{SetPlaylistData(store.getState().reducer.playlist)})`

and the gonna call unsubscribe() but idk how this work inside the useEffect

Comment: You'll have to store a reference to `unsubscribe` using a hook and then call it in your `useEffect`'s return. If you create an Expo Snack with a [mre], I can show your more precise code, but as it stands, I'm not sure what library you're using here, so it's not possible to give a concrete answer.

Comment: so i wont be needing the `let isMounted` variable?

Comment: No -- see my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is the **common warning from the React** when there is a state update statement executed, **when component is unmounted from the view hierarchy**.

checkout the demo below

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

const Demo = props => {
    // ** States
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    // ** Refs
    const mountedRef = useRef(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        mountedRef.current = true // mounted
        return () => {
            mountedRef.current = false // unmounted
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        mountedRef.current && setLoading(true) // update state after verifying the screen mounted status
    }, [])

    // Any other functions or listeners
    const btnPressHandler = () => {
        mountedRef.current && setLoading(true) // update state after verifying the screen mounted status
    }
    
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Demo for handle warning of cannot update state on an unmounted component</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

export default Demo
```